# Find closest element in the DOM with multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search a way to find the top element in the DOM with multiple selector.

```
$('#myDiv').magicFunction('.dark, .light');
```

In this case, return `<div class="dark"></div>`:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="dark"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, return `<div class="light"></div>`:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="jedi"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dark"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this?

```
$('#myDiv').find('.dark, .light').first();
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal happens with me at least 10 times a day. welcome to the club :)